# Mongoose | How to remove duplicate error from this mongoose schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I got this error on my console :

> { MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: mean.companies
>   index: students_1 dup key: { : undefined }
>       at C:\mean\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\pool.js:595:61
>       at authenticateStragglers (C:\mean\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\pool.js:513:16)
>       at Connection.messageHandler (C:\mean\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\pool.js:549:5)
>       at emitMessageHandler (C:\mean\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\connection.js:309:10)
>       at Socket. (C:\mean\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\connection.js:452:17)
>       at Socket.emit (events.js:180:13)
>       at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:269:12)
>       at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:256:11)
>       at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:213:10)
>       at TCP.onread (net.js:581:20)   name: 'MongoError',   message: 'E11000 duplicate key error collection: mean.companies index:
>   students_1 dup key: { : undefined }',   ok: 0,   errmsg: 'E11000
>   duplicate key error collection: mean.companies index: students_1 dup
>   key: { : undefined }',   code: 11000,   codeName: 'DuplicateKey' }

I have 2 schema User and Company, and I'd like to connect each other with a key :
This is my Uschema

```
const UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
nama:{
    type    : String
},
email:{
    type    : String,
    require : true,
    unique : true
},
nim:{
    type    : String,
    require : true,
    unique  : true
},
jurusan:{
    type : String
},
prodi:{
    type : String
},
angkatan:{
    type : String
},
password:{
    type    : String,
    require : true
},
company:{
    type : String,
    ref  : 'company',
    unique  : false
}
```

});

And this is CompanySchema :

```
const CompanySchema = mongoose.Schema({
    perusahaan:{
        type    : String,
        require : true
    },
    deskripsi:{
        type    : String,
        require : true
    },
    alamat:{ 
        type    : String,
        require : true
    },
    email_perusahaan:{
        type    : String,
        require : true
    },
    telepon:{
        type    : String,
        require : true
    },
    website:{
        type    : String,
        require : true
    },
    status:{
        type    : String,
        require : false
    },
    students:[{
        type: String,
        ref: 'user',
        unique  : false
    }]
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> open mongo shell from terminal and use your database with name "mean"

and write this

```
db.companies.dropIndex("students_1");

**OR remove all indexes.**

db.companies.dropIndexes();
```